# How to generate RSA public key .pem file from xcode?

Tags: ios

I need a public key to decrypt RSA private key encrypted data using modulus and exponent in my iOS project. so someone please sugest me how can I create **Public key** using **Modulus** and **Exponent**??

Comment: In general data is encrypted with the public key. Signing is done with the private key.

Comment: Hi Zaph, In my scenerio I need a public key to decrypt server data which was encoded with private key.so please suggest me how can I create  RSA Public key at run time using modulus and exponent to decrypt data ?

Answer (score 1):

I am framing this as an answer due to the length and the confusing question.

Perhaps there is a misunderstanding of "private" vs "secret" keys and asymmetric vs symmetric key encryption.

Asymmetric key encryption such as RSA is not generally used to encrypt data because of two main reasons: 1. The data size is limited to less than the key size so a 2048-bit key can encrypt less than 256-bytes. 2. It is very slow.

It is generally used to encrypt symmetric keys and sign data. Encryption is done with the public key and decryption is done with the private key. Thus many people can use the public key to encrypt data and only the owner of the private key can decrypt the data. For signing the private key is used so anyone with the public key can verify.

Asymmetric key encryption such as AES is used to encrypt data because: 1. The data size is unlimited. 2. It is very fast.

In situations where asymmetric keys are required and data larger than the asymmetric key needs to be encrypted hybrid encryption is used. This is done by creating a random symmetric secret key and encrypting the data with symmetric encryption (such as AES), the symmetric key is encrypted with asymmetric key encryption (such as RSA). The asymmetric key and the encrypted data are then combined.

Comment: Hi Zaph, 
Thanks for your support.I have payload size of 128 byte (confidential data) encrypted with using RSA private key and also I have modulus and exponent. How  I decrypt this payload data using public key?

Comment: You would be beast off describing exactly what you are trying to accomplish because it seems the encryption is not being designed correctly since encryption not done with private keys. If the issue is data in transit between a server and client HTTPS is the general solution.

Comment: Thanks Zaph for support !!